# Excel VBA FOR loop putting values in random cells

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am currently writing a piece of code that finds out how many months are in between two dates, and then writes each month as a date value to a particular cell. The eventual aim is to have the dates in one single column. The code is as follows, I'm sure it could've been done simpler but I'm still learning:

```
For i = 1 To datedifference

    reminderdate = DateAdd("m", -1, reminderdate)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Value = reminderdate

Next i
```

This works generally, however it put the date values in a seemingly random place, and whats more, this place changes every time I run the code. Sometimes the values are placed in column i and sometimes they are placed somewhere offscreen. Only rarely do they actually appear in the column I would like.

This is a very strange issue and I haven't come across anything like it before, I have a hunch I'm just overloading excel but I'm not sure how to make the code more efficient. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not directly specify the cell colum values like Cells(). Also avoid using .Select

Comment: Hi Siva thanks for the response. I have to use select or some function like that because the macro is part of a userbox, and so it has to put the values in different cells each time. Not sure if that gets my point across but essentially I need to use relative references and cant use absolute cell locations.

Comment: @Ruthus99 just as Siva mentions `.Select` is something you should avoid. You could easily do `ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Value = reminderdate`. However is there more code, with your current code nothing shows any logic in what your explaining is the problem.

Comment: Hi DragonSamu thanks for the reply. Yeah I've heard nothing but bad things about select but weirdly its the only one that actually works in entering the monthly increments. When I use "activate" then "activecell.value = " only one cell is filled with data. When I just tried your solution the same thing happened, very strange!

Comment: Ah OK now we're getting  somewhere, realised that it wasn't actually just putting the data in random cells, but rather was using the active cell, which was just the last "random" one I clicked. Is there a way to make the last cell edited the active cell? Thanks

Comment: If you really need to focus on specific `Cells` to be edited I would suggest to look at creating a [Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) that returns the date if the `Cell` is changed